# Formato Data yyyy-mm-ddTHH:mm:ssZ para dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm

Tags: java

Eu recebo no JSON um campo de data "created_at": "2013-01-08T20:11:48Z" e queria apresentar na tela no formado do Brasil mas não consigo usar o SimpleDateFormat para formatar e apresentar de forma alguma.

Answer (score 2):

Segue solução abaixo:

```
String dataJson = "2013-01-08T20:11:48Z".replaceAll("T", " ").replaceAll("Z", "");
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss");

Date dataFormatada = new Date(format.parse(dataJson).getTime());
System.out.println(dataFormatada);
```

Acesse [aqui](https://ideone.com/sWiX2E) para ver o resultado.

Comment: A data agora esta saindo assim:
Thu Mar 09 08:14:00 GMT-03:00 ..........

Comment: No meu computador apareceu assim: Tue Jan 08 20:11:48 GMT 2013

Comment: Verifique a configuração de UTC do seu computador

Answer (score 1):

Tente usar a nova API de data do Java 8 dessa forma:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String data = "2013-01-08T20:11:48Z";
    DateTimeFormatter originalFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
    DateTimeFormatter targetFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

    // Com isso já da pra fazer várias manipulações interessantes
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(data, originalFormat);

    // ou assim
    DateTimeFormatter formatador = DateTimeFormatter
        .ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.MEDIUM)
        .withLocale(new Locale("pt", "br"));

    System.out.println(data);
    System.out.println(dateTime.format(targetFormat));
    System.out.println(dateTime.format(formatador));
}
```

Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/T8G0z2).

Outras referências:

[Conheça a nova API de datas do Java 8](http://blog.caelum.com.br/conheca-a-nova-api-de-datas-do-java-8/)